# How can I get the correct index of a TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, tableview

I have a UILabel inside a TableView and that UILabel is attached to a GestureRecognizer . What I am trying to do is change the color of the UILabel to red on label tap. Right now I am very close when the UILablel is tapped the Label changes to red however the wrong TableCell is changing color. If I tap cell 3 then I want the UILabel in cell 3 to change color not cell 4 or 5.

```
class HomeProfilePlacesCell: NSObject {

    var CellCopy: HomeTVC?

    @objc func PostTap(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer) {

         // This works but it often changes wrong cell
         CellCopy?.post.textColor = UIColor.red
    }

    func HomeProfilePlaceTVC(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, streamsModel : streamModel,HOMEPROFILE: HomeProfile, controller: UIViewController) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeTVC", for: indexPath) as! HomeTVC
        CellCopy = cell

        let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(PostTap(_:)))
        tapGesture.delegate = self as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

        cell.post.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        cell.post.text = streamsModel.Posts[indexPath.row]
        cell.post.tag = indexPath.row

        return cell 
    }
}
```

Again the code is working correctly I just need to find a way to path the Index of the cell clicked to the PostTap method so it can change the color of the correct cell tapped. Any help or suggestion would be great. I do not want to use Table Reload since I am only changing 1 UILabel in the cell clicked.

Comment: Always a bad idea to try to hold onto a reference to a cell (`CellCopy`). Don't do it.

Comment: you need to change only one label colour at a time or, need to change every tabbing label colour?

Answer (score 5):

There is no need to get index of cell, in which the label Taped. `UIGestureRecognizer` has a `UIView` that gesture is attached to, so to change the label color just do in your `PostTap` method:

```
sender.view?.backgroundColor = .red
```

Comment: Fantastic answer!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass the index to your postTap-Method you could subclass UITapGestureRecognizer and add a property like:

```
class CellGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer {
     var indexPath: IndexPath?
}
```

Now you can use your CellGestureRecognizer like:

```
let cellGestureRecognizer = CellGestureRecognizer()
cellGestureRecognizer.indexPath = yourIndexPath
```

I am not exactly sure, if that is what you want. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

**viewDidLoad:**

```
for i in 0..<50 {

    favStatusDict.setValue("0", forKey: String(i))
}
```

**cellForRowAt indexPath:**

```
 let tapGest = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(FirstViewController.favouritesTapped))
 tapGest.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
 cell.btn.tag = indexPath.row
 cell.btn.addGestureRecognizer(tapGest)

 if favStatusDict.value(forKey:(String(indexPath.row))) as? String == "1" {

    cell.btn.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0/255, green: 61/255, blue: 114/255, alpha: 1.0)
 }

 else {

    cell.btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
 }
```

**To change the color:**

```
   func favouritesTapped(sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        let tag: Int = (sender.view?.tag)!
        favStatusDict.setValue("1", forKey: String(tag))
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the `selectedBackgroundView` to the `cell`. This will change the color of the only selected cell and Also you can change Font Color and other stuff too.

```
func HomeProfilePlaceTVC(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, streamsModel : streamModel,HOMEPROFILE: HomeProfile, controller: UIViewController) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeTVC", for: indexPath) as! HomeTVC
    CellCopy = cell

let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(PostTap(_:)))
tapGesture.delegate = self as? UIGestureRecognizerDelegate

cell.post.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

cell.post.text = streamsModel.Posts[indexPath.row]
cell.post.tag = indexPath.row

// MARK: Add SelectedView to TableViewCell

let selectedView:UIView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cell!.frame.size.width, height: cell!.frame.size.height))

  selectedView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

  cell!.selectedBackgroundView = selectedView

return cell 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the text color of the label by simply overriding the `isSelected` variable of the cell. In this case, you don't need to add tap gesture as `UITableView` automatically send the trigger `isSelected` whenever you will tap on any cell. Below is the source code without adding `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the label.

```
    class HomeTVC : UITableViewCell {
       @IBOutlet weak var post: UILabel!

        @objc func postTap(_ sender: Any) {
            self.isSelected = !self.isSelected
        }

        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()

            //Need if you want to change the color only on label tap, not on corresponding cell tap
            let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(postTap(_:)))
            tapGesture.delegate = self
            self.post.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            self.post.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
        }

        override var isSelected: Bool {
            willSet {
                self.post.textColor = newValue ? UIColor.red : UIColor.black
            }
        }
    }
```

If you have more then one label in cell and you need to change the color of text only on label tap, not on cell tap then you need to add `UITapGestureRecognizer` to the label and change selected state on gesture callback, as mention in above code block.